# How to add Dictionary of class objects in to view state

Tags: asp.net, object, viewstate

I'm having a `[Serializable] class` with some `properties,methods and some web controls`.
Using this `class` i were made a `Dictionary<string,object>` variable.
This `Dictionary variable` contains various `objects` of my class.
Now i need to store this `Dictionary variable` into `view-state` so that i can use this `Dictionary variable` on every `post-back` of my web form.
When i use this line of code to store my `Dictionary variable` into `view-state`

> ViewState[this.ClientID + "_CtrAdd"] = dictControl;

It throws error:

> Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' in Assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.

### Note:

```
My class objects contains some web controls.
```

Can any one tell me how can i store this `Dictionary variable` into an `View-state` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests, you can't store certain classes, i.e. those that aren't marked as serializable, in ViewState. This is because ViewState is stored as a BASE64-encoded string in a hidden field on the page, and as such any class that you attempt to store in ViewState must be serializable.

You would have more success building a separate class that just stores data that you need to store in order to have it available in the next postback.

Web controls will store data in view state without you needing to do anything, so perhaps your class can just store the control's ID which you can then use to reference the control later on.

For example:

```
[Serializable]
class MyCustomData
{
    public string TextBoxID1 { get; set; }
    public int MyCounter { get; set;}
    public decimal MyTotal { get; set; }
}

var data = new MyCustomData { TextBoxID1 = txtMyTextBox.ID, MyCounter = anInt, MyTotal = aDecimal };
ViewState[this.ClientID + "_Data"] = data;
```

Comment: You mean to say that.The only way to achieve this i need to inherit all control classes which classes i used in my custom class and also make them serializable.

Comment: No, that wouldn't help as the subclass (the built-in control class) still wouldn't be serializable. What I am suggesting is that you build a class or a struct that stores all the relevant data for your logic as well as any control IDs that you need to reference. I have updated my answer with a quick example.

Answer (score 1):

Your exception is realy clear about what to do. You need to store the data inside your dictonary, not the controls. Controls refrence to many objects, all these object whould have to be saved, that is why controls are not serializable. You also want to keep your ViewState as small as possible, the size will have a significant inpact on your performance.